# ASP.NET server tags are not well formed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use some server tags in OnClientClick of LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnID" OnClientClick='<%# "window.open('SomePage.aspx?Id=" + Eval("reqID") + "');" %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reqID")%>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

how to write this, it is giving the error that Server tags are not well formed.

So how to write this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in code behind as well

```
lnkbtnID.Attributes.Add("onclick","window.open('SomePage.aspx?Id="+reqID+"');");

lnkbtnID.Text=reqID;
```

Comment: I don't know why but it is not working from code behind, so I am trying to write in HTML page itself. In codebehind it is not opening the window but when I checked view source of that page then the window.open contains the right parameters.

Comment: @Nits,do you have any popup blockers in browser which are preventing window.open calls ?
also , can you provide snippet of generated html markup ?

Comment: generated mark-up I checkeda and it is totally correct. Also there are no popup blocker in there.

Answer (score -1):

How about that

```
<a class="NewslinkButton" onclick="myRef = window.open(''+'<%# "SomePage.aspx?NewsID="+Eval("reqID") >','mywin','left=20,top=20,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,height=300');myRef.focus()">
<asp:Literal ID="l1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("reqID")%>'></asp:Literal></a>
```